# SELECT FOR UPDATE in Doctrine 2 DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm

I use pessimistic locking quite a lot in my application, and it works fine when using the Entity Manager:

```php
$em->find($class, $id, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

This results in a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` when using MySQL.

Now I need to use the same locking but for entities retrieved with a DQL query.

**Is it possible to use pessimistic locking in DQL?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the solution, using [Query::setLockMode()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.html#_setLockMode):

```php
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT ...');
$query->setLockMode(LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```